# Condição IF dentro de _Layout.cshtml em MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net, razor

Tenho duas `_Shared.cshtml` (tipo masterpage do MVC, não sei o nome) e ambos são praticamente iguais, só o menu a esquerda é diferente.

Gostaria de fazer apenas 1 e de acordo com a querystring eu chamarei a pagina que quero para ser o menu: ex

```
@if (Request.FilePath.Contains("Home")) 
@ { $("#IDMenu").load('menu_Home.html'); }
@ else
@ { $("#IDMenu").load('menu_Admin.html'); }
```

Mais ou menos isso.

Basicamente hoje minha aplicação tem 2 url

localhost:47123/**home**/

ou

localhost:47123/**Admin**/

se for Admin quero que chame menu_admin.html se for a home chamará outra página.

Não sei como utilizar os Razors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você queira escrever, através do Razor, um código JavaScript para ser interpretado do lado do cliente, você pode utilizar a tag `<text>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//código JavaScript

@if (Request.FilePath.Contains("Home")) {
    <text>
    $("#IDMenu").load('menu_Home.html');
    //mais código JavaScript
    </text>
} else {
    <text>
    $("#IDMenu").load('menu_Admin.html');
    //mais código JavaScript
    </text>
}

//código JavaScript

</script>
```

Existe mais sobre esse assunto nessa [outra questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)

Comment: o quer seria essa tag <text> ? vou testar, mas parece que é isso mesmo

Comment: Essa tag `<text>` serve para enviar para o cliente todo o texto que estiver entre `<text>` e `</text>`, de maneira intocada pelo servidor ;)

Comment: outro detalhe.minha url
http://localhost:47123/Home/contatos_visualizar?id=1

@if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("Home")) { esta dando false, não era pra encontrar?

Comment: Na verdade, não. Porque sua `QueryString`, nesse caso, e apenas `id=1`. Contudo, a propriedade `Request.Path` te retornaria `"/Home/contatos_visualizar"`

Answer (score 0):

Tinhas forma mais fácil de fazer isso. Como?

Se apenas o menu da esquerda é que muda, basta colocares antes do menu:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
    {
        //MENU DA ESQUERDA PARA ADMIN
    }
}   
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Home"))
    {
        //MENU DA ESQUERDA PARA Home
    }
}
```

Eu faria assim. Embora também ache a resposta do @carlosrafaelgn simples e com menos "confusão" de código na mesma Partial

**EDIT**
Reparei agora que querias que a URL também mudasse, este exemplo que coloquei não resolve isso. Vou deixar na mesma a resposta, pode ser útil para casos de restringir acessos